# Java EL object `${pools}`

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I'm trying to adapt the code used in [PSI Probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) (or more generally, the idea of PSI Probe) to be used inside of my company's web application. I can get the majority of the portions of what I'm looking to do, but I have become stuck on one bit of code - the 'Status' tab.  One column of data is the processing time for the thread, data I would really like to have, but I can't figure out where it is coming from.  Here's the relevant snippet:

```
<c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool" varStatus="poolStatus">
  <div class="poolInfo">
    <h3>${pool.name}</h3>
    <div class="processorInfo">
      <span class="name">
        <spring:message code="probe.jsp.status.processor.maxTime"/>
      </span>
      &nbsp;${pool.maxTime}
```

I can't figure out where the `pools` object is coming from! Does anyone have experience with this sort of thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code (this being Google code, a Google search works really quick)

the pools is being populated in the [`ListThreadPoolsController`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#-GACqSKonXw/trunk/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/psiprobe/controllers/threads/ListThreadPoolsController.java&q=pools%20package%3ahttp://psi-probe%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=3)

```
List pools = containerListenerBean.getThreadPools();
        return new ModelAndView(getViewName())
                .addObject("pools", pools);
```

A closer look at [`ContainerListenerBean`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#-GACqSKonXw/trunk/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/psiprobe/beans/ContainerListenerBean.java&q=file%3a%28/%7C%5E%29com/googlecode/psiprobe/beans/ContainerListenerBean%5C.java%24&exact_package=http://psi-probe.googlecode.com/svn&l=1)

shows the properties which are listed in `status.jsp`

```
<span class="name"><spring:message code="probe.jsp.status.currentThreadCount"/></span>&nbsp;${pool.currentThreadCount}
<span class="name"><spring:message code="probe.jsp.status.currentThreadsBusy"/></span>&nbsp;${pool.currentThreadsBusy}
<span class="name"><spring:message code="probe.jsp.status.maxThreads"/></span>&nbsp;${pool.maxThreads}
<span class="name"><spring:message code="probe.jsp.status.maxSpareThreads"/></span>&nbsp;${pool.maxSpareThreads}
<span class="name"><spring:message code="probe.jsp.status.minSpareThreads"/></span>&nbsp;${pool.minSpareThreads}
```

are being populated in the `getThreadPools()`  method

```
ThreadPool threadPool = new ThreadPool();
threadPool.setName(executorName.getKeyProperty("name"));
threadPool.setMaxThreads(JmxTools.getIntAttr(server, executorName, "maxThreads"));
threadPool.setMaxSpareThreads(JmxTools.getIntAttr(server, executorName, "largestPoolSize"));
threadPool.setMinSpareThreads(JmxTools.getIntAttr(server, executorName, "minSpareThreads"));
threadPool.setCurrentThreadsBusy(JmxTools.getIntAttr(server, executorName, "activeCount"));
threadPool.setCurrentThreadCount(JmxTools.getIntAttr(server, executorName, "poolSize"));
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know about the Google code search functionality - that is very handy!

Answer (score 2):

It can come from two places, generally. A Servlet that is invoked before the JSP or a Filter. Check all filters, and the servlet mapped to the url you are opening.

Comment: Is there any better way than just slogging through the decompiled source?

Comment: well, you can get the sources